# Display YouTube video from URL

Tags: javascript, php, html, youtube

I want to load you tube video in my php script.

I have already tried with iframe but it can not work.

I also did some research but it said that load YouTube URL with embed tag, but I want to load without embed tag.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Why do you not want to load it "with embed tag"?

Comment: This is all documented by youtube, the various ways to display their videos

Comment: include your source

Answer (score 0):

1. Sign in to your YouTube account on a computer.
2. On the left side of the page, select the playlist you want to embed.
3. Copy the playlist ID from the URL.
4. Modify the embed code for an individual video by doing the following:
5. In the place of the video ID (after "embed/"), substitute "videoseries?list=".
6. Then paste the playlist ID after the "=".
7. Paste the code into your blog or website HTML.

**Example:**

​`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLx0sYbCqOb8TBPRdmBHs5Iftvv9TPboYG" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en

Comment: While this may answer the question, 
[it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the 
essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Updated Answer.

Comment: I dont want to include embed code.I just inlcude YouTube Url like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fe7uaXzQ1Dc

Comment: Do you want to do that, directly on your `<a href="">` tab? using Php?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this within php as you say then you echo an iframe with the address of the YouTube video as `https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOID` where `VIDEOID` is the part in the YouTube URL after the `v?=`, for example this video `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UaaXEX-MGuk` would be embedded as follows:

```
echo '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UaaXEX-MGuk" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```

Otherwise you can just embed with HTML. Can you provide more detail if this doesn't help?

More here: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en